# Access Program Thread context through kernel without suspend the process

Tags: c++, windows, kernel, reverse-engineering, windows-kernel

I'm trying for research purpose to access the thread context or just the Rip reg, from a kernel driver of some programs, what i tried is PsGetContextThread but isn't helping to get the current context of the thread, the rip stay the same, i have the pointer of the ETHREAD if it's help.

Comment: Is the thread just doing arithmetic or does it call functions that switch to kernel mode? Do you have many free cores so the thread effectively has unlimited timeslice?

Comment: hey thanks for the replay, about the thread doing call function to switch into the kernel i guess no, but i'm trying to reading thread context through the kernel without suspend the thread, there is a way to do it?

Comment: Can't you just make the thread call Sleep(1) in a loop or whatever during testing? When the thread is actually running in user-mode its registers are in the CPU, not in a context you can read.

Comment: @Anders Hey, i don't want to effect the program, everything has to be in the "silence" way, how can i access the registers in the cpu in that case?

Comment: @Anders Are you still alive XD?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't try Sleep in a test application.

Comment: @Anders hey, because i want to search for specifix conext value, and the program can't run with sleep every mil second, so i would like to do it without effect the program running, there is a way to read the context without change the program behavior?, i mean i need to follow rip reg for everystep hes doing

Comment: Stop PM'ing me please. Just get the concept working in a test app before trying something else...